# How to use shiny reactive functions for plotting an sf object that mapped a numeric column based on its quantiles

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, shiny, r-sf

I am trying to use select input that filters the data based on a categorical column, `income_grp` in my example, and then use `geom_sf` to draw a map of a numerical column like `pop_est` with color categories as its quantiles. I try with below code and I got error: You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive consumer.
Hopefully I could be able to draw a map like the image below in a shiny context with. Thanks a lot for any help on this.

```
library(shiny)
library(sf)

shp <- rnaturalearth::ne_countries(returnclass = "sf", scale = 'large')

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}"),
  absolutePanel(top = 10, right = 10,
                selectInput("income", label = "select income gorup", choices = unique(shp$income_grp))
  ),
  plotOutput("map", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  shp_filtered <- reactive({
    shp %>%
      filter(income_grp == input$income)
  })
  
  quantiles <- reactive({
    shp_filtered() %>%
      pull(var = pop_est) %>%
      quantile(probs = seq(0, 1, length.out = 4), na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
      as.vector()
  })
  
  labels <- reactive({
    imap_chr(quantiles(), function(x, idx){
      return(paste0(round(quantiles()[idx], 0), 
                    "%", " – ", round(quantiles()[idx + 1], 0), "%"))
    })
  })
  
  labels() <- labels()[1:length(labels()) - 1]
  
  shp_final <- reactive({
    shp_filtered() %>%
      mutate(mean_quantiles = cut(pop_est,
                                  breaks = quantiles(),
                                  labels = labels(),
                                  include.lowest = T))
  })
  
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    shp_final() %>%
      ggplot() +
      geom_sf(aes(fill = mean_quantiles))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following change gives the output:

```
#labels() <- labels()[1:length(labels()) - 1]
  
  shp_final <- reactive({
    mylabels <- labels()[1:length(labels()) - 1]
    shp_filtered() %>%
      mutate(mean_quantiles = cut(pop_est,
                                  breaks = quantiles(),
                                  labels = mylabels,
                                  include.lowest = T))
  })
```

[image: output]